# Display won't inline-block

Tags: html, css, eclipse

The divs won't line up horizontally. I used display: inline-block but it still won't work. The divs still align vertically. I'm still not sure why. I'm creating a dynamic web project. I'm using Eclipse as my IDE and I'm editing the HTML produced via PrintWriter in my Java Servlet. What I'm trying to inline-block here is the info below the "Educational Background"

CSS:

@CHARSET "ISO-8859-1";

```
body
{
    background-image: url("images/wood.jpg");
    font-family: Garamond;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.paper
{
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 900px;
    height: 100%;
    margin-top: 40px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 20px 5px black;
}

.level1, .level2, .level3
{
    display: inline-block
}

/*.upper
{
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}*/
```

HTML from Servlet:

```
 pw.println("<!DOCTYPE html>"
            + "<html> <head> <title> Curriculum Vitae </title> <link href=\"cv.css\" rel=\"stylesheet\">"
            + "<body><div class=\"main\" align=\"center\">"
            + "             <div class=\"paper\" align=\"left\">"  
            + "                 <div class=\"upper\">"
            + "                     <div class=\"basicInfo\">"
            + "                     <div class=\"name\"><h2>" + lastName + ", " + firstName +" "+ middleName + "</h2></div>"
            +                       homeAddress + "<br>" + provincialAddress + "<br>" + contactDetails + "<br>" + birthdate + "<br>" + maritalStatus + "<br><br></div>"
            + "                     <div class=\"image\">" + imageURL + "</div>"
            + "                 </div>"
            + "                 <div class=\"educationInfo\">" 
            + "                 <h3 align=\"left\"> Educational Background </h3>"
            + "                     <br><div class=\"level1\">" + tSchool + "<br>" + tCourse + "<br> Completed Years: " + tInclusiveYears + "<br> Awards: " + tHonorsReceived + "<br></div>"
            + "                     <br><div class=\"level2\">" + sSchool + "<br>Secondary<br> Completed Years: " + sInclusiveYears + "<br> Awards: " + sHonorsReceived + "<br></div>"
            + "                     <br><div class=\"level3\">" + pSchool + "<br>Primary<br> Completed Years: "  + pInclusiveYears + "<br> Awards: " + pHonorsReceived + "<br></div>"
            + "                 </div>"
            + "             </div>"
            + "     </div>"
            + "</body>"
            + "</html>");
```

Comment: Did you try zooming out your `divs` are `900px` wide. Try zooming out on this http://jsfiddle.net/akshay7/2bmL7ryv/

Comment: I just did and nothing happened

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my understanding, you want div with class level 1, level 2 and level 3 should align horizontally. So to achieve this, remove "br" tags from the starting of each div and then apply "display:inline-block;" in each div.

Answer (score 1):

Because you've separated your HTML tags with spaces, your DIVs could be wrapping down.

Add

```
white-space: nowrap;
```

to your CSS.

Answer (score 0):

If you want divs to line up horizontally.

You should set the css style for all of divs, like the following example:

```
<style>
    .inline{
       width: 100px;
       display: inline-block;
    }

</style>
<div class="inline">content 1</div>
<div class="inline">content 2</div>
```